# How to sort cells in a column from A to Z?

Tags: excel, vba

The code is from slightly edited macro. I tried to remove the 'messy code', however it is not working. The aim of it is to sort data in column BF from A to Z.

```
 Dim InSheet As Worksheet
    Set InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A to Z")
 Dim LastRow as Integer
   LastRow = InSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 58).End(xlUp).Row

 InSheet.Select
     Columns("BF:BF").Select
 InSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
 InSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "BF1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
  With InSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:BF" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

SO I tried this and it is not working:

```
 Dim InSheet As Worksheet
    Set InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A to Z")
 Dim LastRow as Integer
   LastRow = InSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 58).End(xlUp).Row

 InSheet.Columns("BF:BF")
 InSheet.Sort.SortFields.Clear
 InSheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
    "BF1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortNormal
  With InSheet.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:BF" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Any ideas? I would like to really avoid `.select` an other stuff as it is hugely decreasing performance.

Comment: +1 for `I would like to really avoid .select an other stuff`. Just remove this line `InSheet.Columns("BF:BF")` and code should work and also change `.SetRange Range("A1:BF" & LastRow)` to `.SetRange InSheet.Range("A1:BF" & LastRow)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used advice provided by both Steven Martin's answer and Dmitry Pavliv's comment, and this is working pretty well:

```
Dim InSheet As Worksheet
    Set InSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("A to Z")
    Dim LastRow As Integer
        LastRow = InSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 58).End(xlUp).Row

With InSheet.Sort  ' sort data from A to Z
    .SetRange InSheet.Range("A1:BF" & LastRow)
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just directly sort the Range with a Key with out the rest of the code you have.

```
Range("A1:BF" & LastRow).SORT Key1:=Range("BF1"), Order1:=xlAscending_
        Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:= _
        xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```